# VistaBridge and Desktop window manager in WPF 4

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-4.0

I have started using WPF a short while back, and I'm in the progress of reading the book Pro WPF in C# 2008.

Here they are using P/Invoke to "DmwApi.dll" to create Aero glass effect on windows, and they use the VistaBridge created by MS to create the new Task Dialog boxes.

So basically what I'm curious about is if WPF 4 (that is not covered by the book) include this as a built in functionality, so we don't have to use P/Invoke or a extra library to obtain this useful functionality.

It really *feels* like this should be a integrated part of WPF.

If it's still not there, so anyone know if MS plans to make this a integrated part in a future version of WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain parts are, certain parts aren't.

**Integrated**

- Displaying a progress bar overlayed on the task bar button;

**Not integrated**

- Task dialog;
- Aero glass.

*Feel free to expand this list if you know more.*

Comment: So basically your answer is no ;). I'll give it some time to see if any other answer is given on this before I mark this as the accepted answer.